# Is there a way to force automatic truncation of characters in a cell when opening a spreadsheet to prevent the 32,767 overflow?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2016

I'm working with a system that consistently generates datasets with one column that contains cells with characters over Excel's 32,767 character limit, which causes the characters to overflow onto the next line, messing up the entire spreadsheet.

[Example of Overflow Issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tHGJ6.png)

Unfortunately, I can't stop the system from generating data in this way, but I was wondering if there was a way to get excel to force automatic truncation of cell content at the 32767 character limit (or less), or to set a predefined character limit on cell content so it doesn't overflow and mess up the entire document when opening the file?

I know that data validation can set a character limit on cells so users can't enter in cells past that, but what I was hoping for was to set this limit/automatic truncation so the overflow doesn't happen in the first place, and the whole document doesn't get messed up.

I usually hand this data off to other users who wouldn't recognize/know how to deal with the overflow issue, which is why I would rather just truncate the cell content for them, if possible.

Any help is much appreciated, thanks!

Comment: AFAIK, something else is happening. Excel does not automatically overflow if you try to enter `2^15` or more characters in a cell. Possible something in how the data set items are being entered into your worksheet?  How is that being accomplished?

Comment: Is the dataset in the format of `.csv` or `.xlsx`? Can you use Google Sheets instead of Excel?

Comment: @RonRosenfeld yes the data isn't being entered in manually in excel. It's produced by a script on R that writes the data to a csv file. But because of excel's inability to contain cell contents with character lengths >32,767, I get the overflow when I open the csv file on excel. 

I was just wondering if there was any way I could get excel to just truncate the contents instead of overflowing.

Comment: @harrymc it's in the format of the .csv file. And I did not know that Google Sheets had a higher character count limit of 50,000! I will probably still need to truncate the cells somehow, but that's useful to know, and that work around should be able to deal with some of my datasets! Thanks! I would upvote if I could.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest **importing** the CSV file using `Power Query` available in Excel 2010+,

The limit for PQ for the number of characters in a cell (*preview cell* as they call it) is 1,000,000.

You can then Truncate (or Split) the column as you prefer to not exceed the size limits of Excel, and save the results to Excel.

You can do all that from the Power Query UI.  Or you could write code to split on a word or sentence ending.

If that is not enough, you could write a VBA routine for which the limit, if I recall correctly, would be at least 1,000,000,000 characters in the VBA variable before truncating/splitting.

Comment: Unfortunately the import tools using Power Query (Get and Transform in newer versions of excel) don't seem to be available for MacOS (which is what a lot of my coworkers and I use to open the CSV files). I tried using the native data import tool for excel for Mac, but unfortunately it still had the overflow issue. 

I'm not too familiar with VBA, so I might have to look more into the specifics of how I would implement this/get my coworkers to use this when I have more time later. Thanks anyway!

Comment: I am reading that some features are available in Excel for Microsoft 365 for Mac.  Unfortunately not Excel 2016 for Mac.

Comment: File handling in VBA will also be different on the Mac. Ron de Bruin as a nice article on [Problems with Apple’s sandbox requirements in Mac Office 2016 and higher with VBA code](https://www.rondebruin.nl/mac/mac034.htm) that may give you some pointers.

Answer (score 0):

One solution to the Excel 32767 characters limit in a cell is to pass via another
product.

This workaround is to open the CSV file in Google Sheets, which has the higher
limit of 50,000 characters, then perform the text-to-columns transformation,
and finally download and open the file in Excel.